# How to combine dynamic columns in Google Sheets while retaining data in other rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a Google Form that asks people to fill out their name, gender, and then their size preference for shirts and pants. The form automatically outputs the 2 sizes in separate columns.

[image]

I want to combine the size columns while retaining the name and gender of the respondents, like this:

[image]

I know I can use arrays and queries to do this:

```
={query({A16:D18},"select Col1, Col2, 'Shirts', Col3 where Col1 is not null");
  query({A16:D18},"select Col1, Col2, 'Pants', Col4 where Col1 is not null")}
```

Which gets me exactly what I want. But I'm trying to make it dynamic in case I need to add more questions in my form about sizes (which increases the # of columns).

Right now if more columns are added, I would have to add another query() line manually and make it look like this:

```
={query({A16:D18},"select Col1, Col2, 'Shirts', Col3 where Col1 is not null");
  query({A16:D18},"select Col1, Col2, 'Pants', Col4 where Col1 is not null");
  query({A16:D18},"select Col1, Col2, 'Dresses', Col5 where Col1 is not null")}
```

Is there any way to dynamically add another `query()` line if I tell it to look for 3 columns now?

I know this seems like weird request if I'm willing to enter in "3" manually - but I want other people in my company to be able to use this spreadsheet and asking them to manually change the # of columns is easier an less error-prone than having them modify the formula.

I know how to dynamically change the `Col#`, just not the extra query line...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to do this and a lot of them can fail when dealt with not-so-skilled users from your company, so I would recommend this solution which is able to account for future possibilities/states without a need for constantly editing and adapting the formula. This formula will look for header and if present it will append whole range.

```
={"Name", "Gender", "Type", "Size"; QUERY(
 {IF($C$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$C$1&"', Col3"), {"","","",""});
  IF($D$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$D$1&"', Col4"), {"","","",""});
  IF($E$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$E$1&"', Col5"), {"","","",""});
  IF($F$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$F$1&"', Col6"), {"","","",""});
  IF($G$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$G$1&"', Col7"), {"","","",""});
  IF($H$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$H$1&"', Col8"), {"","","",""});
  IF($I$1<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$I$1&"', Col9"), {"","","",""})}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0)}
```

[image]

If you want something more user-friendly you can create a selectable menu... something like:

[image]

where **N2** cell is:

```
={"Name", "Gender", "Type", "Size"; QUERY(
 {IF($K$3<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$3&"', Col3"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$4<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$4&"', Col4"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$5<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$5&"', Col5"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$6<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$6&"', Col6"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$7<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$7&"', Col7"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$8<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$8&"', Col8"), {"","","",""});
  IF($K$9<>"", QUERY({$A$2:$I}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$K$9&"', Col9"), {"","","",""})}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0)}
```

cell **J3** is: **`=TRANSPOSE(C1:1)`**

and cell **K3** range has data validation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After searching far and wide I came up with this elegant little solution. It uses `INDIRECT` to add all columns into one as more columns are added. You then use the indirect cell to combine all columns.

1. Specify your `INDIRECT` range in a helper cell first with
   `=B6"&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COUNTA($A$2:$CA$2), 4), 1, "")`
   where B6 is the first cell of data and CA is the furthest column you want to capture.

In my sheet, you get the result: `(B6:Q)`, where the data in columns go from B:Q. If you, for example, add a column of data in R, it changes to `(B6:R)`.

Say you put this formula into cell A1, then:

2. Then to combine all the columns into one:
   `=UNIQUE(flatten(transpose(INDIRECT(A1))))`

Comment: Would you please provide a demonstration of the outcome of this answer in terms of the OP's goal. It's not clear how the helper (in Cell B6) cell relates to the `indirect` formula referencing cell A1. Also, when I enter `=B6"&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COUNTA($A$2:$CA$2), 4), 1, "")`  the formula shown in the cell is actually `=A1"&":"SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COUNTA($A$2:$I$2),4),1,"")"` (same result when I copy/paste the formula from the answer)  and I get a `Formula parse error`.